# Laravel Eloquent Join By Same Foreign_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Besides writing a custom join, is there an easy predefined relationship I can use for this.

I have two models that each belong to a user that I want to connect.

A user has Invoices, which looks like this:

```
id - integer
user_id - integer (foreign_key)
```

And a user has PaymentMethods, which look like this:

```
id - integer
user_id - integer (foreign_key)
type - string
```

What I want to do is on a given invoice I want to get all of the payment methods the user who owns the invoice also owns to have them select which specific one they want to use for that invoice.

I know I can do a custom join where `invoice.user_id = payment_method.user_id`. But I want to know if eloquent already has a built in relationship type to handle this.

My first though naturally was hasManyThough but looking at the docs that's not quite right as it shows the parent model having many intermediate entries each of which has many distant entries as well.

I considered a belongs to many where the user is essentially a pivot table but that would assume the foreign keys would be on the user not each of the related models.

Does Laravel's Eloquent ORM have a built in relationship for this sort of setup?

Comment: Sounds like a simple one-to-many relationship between the User model and the PaymentMethod and Invoice models would suffice. and Yes, Laravel's Eloquent ORM does have a built-in relationship for this sort of setup, and it's called the "has many through" relationship.

Comment: @DLK Actually no as I mentioned hasManyThough was my first thought as well but its based on a different schema. It's basically nested hasMany relations. The example in the docs is a Project hasMany Environments and an Environment hasMany Deployments. Then using hasManyThough a Project hasMany Deployments though many Environments. Its not designed for a parent model that belongs to an intermediate model.

Comment: Too complex to understand for me! tought you want a collection of all payment methods associated with the user who owns the invoice.